# Compilar Aplicación Android con Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

tengo un Problema. Llevó horas intentando compilar esta app Android , con Eclipse pero no logra compilarse

Nota: Eclipse tienes los Complementos Adecuados

1- Eclipse Indigo con JDT plugin

2- Java JDK

3- Developer Tools /  https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

4- SDKManager

Con los Paquetes de:
Android 5.1 (API 21)& Android 2.1
Android Library, 
Android Repository.

Project->properties->Android. He agregado la Librería "appCompat"
Requerida para hacer funcionar Styles.xml

No funciona nada, estoy algo frustrado porque necesito compilar la App,

¿Será que no es posible Con eclipse?

¿Solo se Puede con Android estudio?

espero su ayuda Amigos, Gracias.

Código Fuente:
https://github.com/Floens/Clover

Comment: Si la app fue desarrollada usando Android Studio, deberás compilarla ahí ya que AS usa Gradle como gestor de dependencias y estructura de manera diferente las carpetas de la app. Estas seguro que la app fue desarrollada con eclipse?

Comment: Yo optaría para instalar android studio, es un gran IDE

Comment: Si Android estudio es el mejor pero gasta muchos Recursos :/ y no la app fue creada con Android studio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mirando tu repositorio veo que tu proyecto es gradle:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en los elementos que enumeras **no esta todo lo necesario para compilar un proyecto gradle**, necesitas la herramienta **`Eclipse Gradle (Buildship)`**, que conseguiras en el Eclipse Marketplace.

> Para que no tengas problemas [aqui tienes una guia de instalacion](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGradle/article.html#eclipse-gradle-support-with-buildship).

---

Después de eso, la [importacion de un proyecto gradle](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGradle/article.html#buildship_import) no es demasiado complicada, aqui un resumen:

<kbd>Archivo</kbd> ▸ <kbd>Importar…​</kbd> ▸ <kbd>Gradle</kbd> ▸ <kbd>Proyecto Gradle</kbd>

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aprieta el botón Siguiente y especifica el directorio raiz:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Finaliza o aprieta Next para ajustes personalizados y acepta la previa cuando se muestre, listo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[FUENTE](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGradle/article.html)

Comment: Gracias @Jordi , me has ayudado mucho! Espero de estar forma lograr compilar mi APK , Muchisimas Gracias!